# How can I use variables to dictate array length?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making my first game with Java. I have only just started programming so please don't judge!

I have an array set up at the beginning of my main method, that creates 6 items.

```
Item item[] = new Item[6]
```

However, I have now decided that I want to add more game modes - easy, medium and insane.
Easy will have 6 items,
Medium has 10,
insane has 20.

Here is a skeleton of the code.

```
boolean easy, medium, hard;
int itemnumber
Item item[] = new Item[itemnumber]

public void start(){
    if(easy){
        itemnumber = 6
    }else if(medium){
        itemnumber = 10
    }else if(insane){
        itemnumber = 20
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            item[i] = new SpotPlus(getWidth() + 500 * i);
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics G)
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
       item[i].paint(g);
    }
}
```

I think the issue is that the variable itemnumber is only changed *after* the array is set up. But if I put the array after the if/else, the method paint will be able to "see" the array.

Can anyone think of a way around this issue??
Thanks heaps!

If you need more info don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Why not simply use a `List`?

Comment: where do you assign values to your booleans? initialise the array there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your start method to

```
Item item[];

public void start(){
    if(easy){
        itemnumber = 6
    }else if(medium){
        itemnumber = 10
    }else if(insane){
        itemnumber = 20
    }
    item = new Item[itemnumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            item[i] = new SpotPlus(getWidth() + 500 * i);
    }
```

}

Declare the array on top and initialize it after the itemnumber get assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Should I initialise the array in the paint method as well?

Comment: No need. You are already doing that in start method right ? No need of it. The only thing you need to take care is to call start() method before paint method. Otherwise null pointer exception comes in paint method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using java.util.ArrayList. You'll be able to have a dynamically sized array.

Alternatively, recreate the array in start.

Comment: +1 for ArrayList. It's a data structure much more suited to this kind of behavior. If you're coming to Java from another programming language it may not be obvious that such thing exists, but the entire Java Collections framework will reduce the need to do any kind of array gymnastics in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the variable at the top, and initialize it in the `start()` method:

```
boolean easy, medium, hard;
int itemnumber;
Item[] item; //declaration only

public void start(){
    if(easy){
        itemnumber = 6;
    }else if(medium){
        itemnumber = 10;
    }else if(insane){
        itemnumber = 20;
    }
    item = new Item[itemnumber]; //initialize array
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            item[i] = new SpotPlus(getWidth() + 500 * i);
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics G)
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
       item[i].paint(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, then you would lose the references to all the `SpotPlus` objects you created previously. You need to make sure that `start()` is called first though.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have forgotten semicolons at the end of lines 3 (`Item item[] = new Item[itemnumber]`), 6 (`itemnumber = 6`), 8 (`itemnumber = 10`) and 10 (`itemnumber = 20`), and you have forgotten an opening curly brace in the method `paint` (it should be `public void paint(Graphics G) {`. To solve the array problem, you could do:

```
boolean easy, medium, hard;
int itemnumber;
Item item[];

public void start(){
    if(easy){
        itemnumber = 6;
    }else if(medium){
        itemnumber = 10;
    }else if(insane){
        itemnumber = 20;
    }
        item[] = new Item[itemnumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            item[i] = new SpotPlus(getWidth() + 500 * i);
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics G) {
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
       item[i].paint(g);
    }
}
```